# wget -k -O- never returns

Tags: unix, wget

Does anyone know why

```
wget -O- http://www.google.com
```

and

```
wget -k http://www.google.com
```

work just fine, but

```
    wget -k -O- http://www.google.com
```

... never returns?

Using wget 1.12 under MacOS X and Debian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This call is somewhat nonsensical, because `-k` is for converting links relative to the local storage location, but with `-O-` you are not specifying a local storage location.

What actually appears to happen is that `wget` is attempting to look at the output file after having downloaded it, in order to apply the `-k` modifications, but the output is to the terminal, so it waits on the terminal.  If you send an EOF on the terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), the call terminates.  It obviously can't do anything with what you enter, because the output was already printed.

On might think that `wget` should detect this situation, but note that Unix utilities are generally device independent and quite happily wait on a terminal if you have somehow failed to supply input (compare `grep`).

Comment: Hi Peter, I see you do not have only a deep understanding of Postgreql, but also of Unix too. Thanks for your reply!